# How do I get or initialize the variable that I want?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a simple program, but I meet a problem that the program does not output the given variable "tax" in the end.

```
def main():
    # define and initialize constants and variables
    menu1 = 6
    menu2 = 2.5
    menu3 = 1.25
    menu4 = 3.75
    choose = total = 0
    tax = total*0.06
    
    # display welcome
    print("Welcome to Yum Yum Snack Bar!")
    try:
        while choose != 5:
            print("\nPlease choose from the following menu:")
            print("1) Personal Pizza $6.00")
            print("2) Pretzel $2.50")
            print("3) Chips $1.25")
            print("4) Hot Dog $3.75")
            print("5) Exit ")
            choose = int(input("\nEnter your choice here: "))
            if choose == 1:
                total += menu1
            elif choose == 2:
                total += menu2
            elif choose == 3:
                total += menu3
            elif choose == 4:
                total += menu4
            elif choose == 5:
                continue
            else:
                print("Invalid choice. Must choose 1 – 5. Try again.")
            print("Current total: $",total)
    except:
        print("Invalid choice. Must choose 1 – 5. Try again.")
        main()
    print("Current total: $",total)
    print("Sales tax: $",tax)
    print("Total Bill: $",total+tax)
    print("Have a nice day!")
main()
```

Comment: You are calculating `tax` at the beginning when `total` is 0. Calculate it before printing the value

Comment: What do you mean by "the program does not output the given variable "tax" in the end"? Does it fail to print anything? Does it print only the text? Does it print an unexpected value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problem is solved.Also start using python dictionary instead of using lots of if else statements

```
def main():
    # define and initialize constants and variables
    menu1 = 6
    menu2 = 2.5
    menu3 = 1.25
    menu4 = 3.75
    choose = total = 0
    tax = total*0.06
    
    # display welcome
    print("Welcome to Yum Yum Snack Bar!")
    try:
        while choose != 5:
            print("\nPlease choose from the following menu:")
            print("1) Personal Pizza $6.00")
            print("2) Pretzel $2.50")
            print("3) Chips $1.25")
            print("4) Hot Dog $3.75")
            print("5) Exit ")
            choose = int(input("\nEnter your choice here: "))
            price_dict = {
            1: menu1,
            2: menu2,
            3: menu3,
            4: menu4
            }
          
            if 0 < choose < 5:
                total += price_dict[choose]
            else:
                if choose == 5:
                    continue
                else:        
                    print("Invalid choice. Must choose 1 – 5. Try again.")
            print("Current total: $",total)
    except:
        print("Invalid choice. Must choose 1 – 5. Try again.")
        main()
    tax = total*0.06

    print("Current total: $",total)
    print("Sales tax: $",tax)
    print("Total Bill: $",total+tax)
    print("Have a nice day!")
main()
```

Comment: Wow, I learn a lot from your answer, I will try to practise in this way. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

when you initialized `tax`, you gave it a value of `0` because `total*0.06` at that point equaled zero.

python goes line by line so the variable "`tax`" didn't change its value for the whole code, you only changed "`total`".

so to get the tax, you should calculate it again.

```
print("Current total: $",total)
tax=0.06*total
print("Sales tax: $",tax)
print("Total Bill: $",total+tax)
print("Have a nice day!")
```

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Here the value of total gets updated but the tax is calculated before the check as given below, hence tax will output `tax = total*0.06` where initially `total=0`
Please try this:

```py
def main():
    # define and initialize constants and variables
    menu1 = 6
    menu2 = 2.5
    menu3 = 1.25
    menu4 = 3.75
    choose = total = tax = 0
    # display welcome
    print("Welcome to Yum Yum Snack Bar!")
    try:
        while choose != 5:
            print("\nPlease choose from the following menu:")
            print("1) Personal Pizza $6.00")
            print("2) Pretzel $2.50")
            print("3) Chips $1.25")
            print("4) Hot Dog $3.75")
            print("5) Exit ")
            choose = int(input("\nEnter your choice here: "))
            if choose == 1:
                total += menu1
            elif choose == 2:
                total += menu2
            elif choose == 3:
                total += menu3
            elif choose == 4:
                total += menu4
            elif choose == 5:
                continue
            else:
                print("Invalid choice. Must choose 1 – 5. Try again.")
            print("Current total: $",total)
    except:
        print("Invalid choice. Must choose 1 – 5. Try again.")
    tax = total*0.06
    print("Current total: $",total)
    print("Sales tax: $",tax)
    print("Total Bill: $",total+tax)
    print("Have a nice day!")
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Now your tax is always 0. You have to calculate the tax at the end. Like this:

```
def main():
    # define and initialize constants and variables
    menu1 = 6
    menu2 = 2.5
    menu3 = 1.25
    menu4 = 3.75
    choose = total = 0

    # display welcome
    print("Welcome to Yum Yum Snack Bar!")
    try:
        while choose != 5:
            print("\nPlease choose from the following menu:")
            print("1) Personal Pizza $6.00")
            print("2) Pretzel $2.50")
            print("3) Chips $1.25")
            print("4) Hot Dog $3.75")
            print("5) Exit ")
            choose = int(input("\nEnter your choice here: "))
            if choose == 1:
                total += menu1
            elif choose == 2:
                total += menu2
            elif choose == 3:
                total += menu3
            elif choose == 4:
                total += menu4
            elif choose == 5:
                continue
            else:
                print("Invalid choice. Must choose 1 – 5. Try again.")
            print("Current total: $", total)

    except:
        print("Invalid choice. Must choose 1 – 5. Try again.")
        main()
    print("Current total: $", total)
    tax = total * 0.06
    print("Sales tax: $", tax)
    print("Total Bill: $", total + tax)
    print("Have a nice day!")


main()
```